# AngularJS routing doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I can't implement angularJS routing in my page, when I first made it, it worked, but after browser returns nothing.
Code: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/lIXeC0X6SkzXKcr8hoAp?p=catalogue

app:

```
    angular.module('$routingApp', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'main.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
        }]);
```

Comment: The content of ng-app does not match with the module name.

Comment: why your module name add one more '$' ?

Comment: edited, now code works in plunker, but not on my computer :( the path to main.html is correct

Comment: Have you renamed `$routingApp` to `routingApp` on your local environment as well?

Comment: Could you provide some error logs from console on your computer?

Comment: @AlexSzabó yes I have, but it still returns nothing :(

Comment: @AlexKopachov the problem is that it returns no error logs!

Comment: It's working properly on Plunker?I can see Hello World

Comment: @SatejS yes it does! but when I run THE VERY SAME code on my local enviroment, it returns nothing!

Comment: Okay, two things. 1.Are you including the Angular Routes file(It is now seperate). 2.Are you running this on a server, and not from your file system?

Comment: @SatejS 1. yes I do. 2. from my file system

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 try running it from a server, like Brackets Live Preview?I think i faced a similar issue,this could be the solution.Not sure, but give it a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your module name, as suggest by @sp00m,  see the updated plunkr link below :

```
angular.module('routingApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'main.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }]);
```

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/pTAEymmKGQ3h2V8CW0Uw?p=preview)

Comment: i've already done that and it works in plunkr but not on my computer :(

Comment: I can't figure out what's the problem it looks like some magic that I can't get

Comment: Dud, do one thing, just zip your code exactly on your system & upload to somewhere like dropbox , because i also want to see, what is happening when no issue seems to exist in your code.   Perhaps, something you are missing on your system.

Comment: Are you using internet explorer?

Comment: Do one thing,  use the below cdns for your angular code :             https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js .

Comment: Definitely try running it on a local server, or use Brackets and run it on Live Preview.I have a good feeling this is causing the issue.

Comment: ya, should give it a try.